# Lambda expression: Where clause for Include list

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

So I got something like this:

```
var myObj = db.SomeObject
              .Include("Tasks")
              .SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == someObjectId);

if (myObj != null)
{
    myObj.Tasks = myObj.Tasks.OrderBy(x => x.Number).ToList();
}
```

Here I want to be able to put a condition (`where`) on my Include, for instance:
`.where task.IsDeleted == false`

Thusfar I have not found a solution.

I am aware of the fact that I could use the `where` together with where I order the tasks but this however, does not run on the database but in stead uses memory. I want it to run on the database.

Does anyone here know how I can do this? 
If so, is there also a way to put the `order by` condition to the included list of tasks?

Comment: Don't think it's possible.

Comment: Why don't you just get the tasks?  And Then Just the object without the tasks?

Comment: @sylon: what do you mean?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like this, returs you your original object with its child collection filtered and sorted.

```
SomeObject a = db.SomeObjects.Where(x => x.Id == someobjectid)
                      .Select(
                          x =>
                          new
                              {
                                  someObject = x,
                                  task = x.Tasks.Where(task => task.IsDeleted == false)
                                                .OrderBy(task => whatever)
                              })
                      .Select(x => x.someObject).Single();
```

It's actually loosing the collection of activities in the last select so you can do this :

```
SomeObject a = db.SomeObjects.Where(x => x.Id == someobjectid)
                      .Select(
                          x =>
                          new
                              {
                                  someObject = x,
                                  task = x.Tasks.Where(task => task.IsDeleted == false)
                                                .OrderBy(task => whatever)
                              });
 return a.FirstOrDefault().someObject;
```

Comment: This actually does work and gives me the original object indeed. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

To do this is EF, you need to specify a projection with a `Select` clause.

Something like this will get just the data you want from the db:

```
var anonymous = db.SomeObject.Where( x => x.Id == someObjectId )
  .Select( x => new
    {
      SomeObject = x,
      Tasks = x.Tasks
        .Where( o => !o.IsDeleted )
        .OrderBy( o => ... )
    }
  )
  .SingleOrDefault()
;
```

You will end up with an instance of the anonymous type , but you can easily fix that up on the client:

```
MyObject myObject = anonymous.SomeObject;
myObject.Tasks = anonymous.Tasks;
```

Comment: This might be working, just testing some stuff with this one still.

Comment: FYi -- if you don't want to deal with anonymous objects, you can explicitly cast it to a model in your Select via .Select( x=> new YourModelClass

Answer (score 2):

The simple answer is: You can't do that.

Why? Because you query `SomeObject`.
Each returned `SomeObject` contains all referenced data, because if it wouldn't it wouldn't represent the actual object in the database.

Comment: So what would be a better way of approach? since I have for instance 1000 tasks and I do not want to load all of them since, say, 600 have the `IsDeleted` flag set to `true`

Comment: @Tikkes: I think you want a projection in that case. [Nicholas Butler](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15810444/572644) shows an example for EF.

Answer (score 1):

What about getting them separately:

```
var myObj = db.SomeObject
              .SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == someObjectId);


var tasks = db.SomeObject
              .Where(x => x.Id == someObjectId)
              .SelectMany(x => x.Tasks)
              .Where(x => !x.Deleted);
```